# Updation of object inside observable array is done but changes are not coming on browser

Tags: knockout.js

There is issue which I am facing right now.I have observable array which contains list of objects.Whenever I updating property of any object of array.It is not reflected on browser.I have use all knockout functions like replace,remove.But the updation coming in observable array but not in browser.

Here is a sample of my issue:

```
 var ViewModel=new {
     self=this;
     self.List=ko.observableArray([]); 
              }
     $(function(){
       ko.applyBinding(ViewModel); 
    }) 
    $.post('/url',{},function(data){
        ViewModel.List(data); //data is list having 4 property having CommentList as again object-->id,title,description,CommentList--->commenttitle,commentdescription
      })  
    //During change of property of commentList
    $.post('/updateComment',{},function(obj){//Here obj-->obj.Commenttitle="some title",obj.commentdescription='some description'
       //Let say there require update 4th object of List and  2nd property of CommentList
         ViewModel.AnswerList()[4].CommentList.splice(2,1,obj);

     })
    //But nothing updation on browser
```

Comment: please consider editing your post to precise language, and your problem with some minimal code

Answer (score 3):

You say:

> Whenever I updating property of any object of array it is not
>   reflected on browser.

The properties on the objects in the observable array also need to be set to `ko.observable` for your UI to be automatically updated.

For example:

```
var anObservableArray = ko.observableArray([    
  { name: "A", type: "Type A" }    
]);

// some later point
anObservableArray()[0].name = "B";
```

would **NOT** update your UI as `name` is not an observable.

However,

```
var anObservableArray = ko.observableArray([    
  { name: ko.observable("A"), type: ko.observable("Type A") }    
]);

// some later point
anObservableArray()[0].name("B");
```

..would update your UI to display the name B as `name` is an observable.

EDIT: (After code was added to question)

So from your code you have:

```
 answer=GetAnswerFromViewModel(parentcourseItemID); 
 answer.CommentCount--;                     
 answer.CommentList.splice(CommentIndex,1); 
 answer.CommentText='';
```

assuming `GetAnswerFromViewModel` returns an answer with observable properties, you should be writing:

```
 answer=GetAnswerFromViewModel(parentcourseItemID); 
 answer.CommentCount(answer.CommentCount()--);                     
 answer.CommentList.splice(CommentIndex,1); 
 answer.CommentText('');
```

If the properties on your answer are not observables then your UI will not update.

Comment: But the issue is that the array is coming for server side.

Comment: It's not very clear what the exact problem is. If you have data coming from the server then I suggest you look at the mapping plugin which will transform JSON data (eg. your array) into observable properties. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Actually in mapping it is directly pass data to observableArray.But in my case I get object from serverside which require to update on array and it require to update UI as well

Comment: One more thing after update object in observableArray if we write code as var listObj=ViewModel.AnswerList();            ViewModel.Answer([]);                                ViewModel.Answer(listobj); Then it update UI otherwise not.But this is undesirable.